# How to put an anchor to particular portion of another page in confluence?

Tags: confluence

When I've multiple pages in confluence how can I cross link pages ? I mean link to a purticular portion in another page like anchoring `<a href="otherpage#someplace"> Text </a>`

eg: I have two pages, Index page and Book detail page. I need to link Comments in Index page to Comments in Book detail page.

Index page

```
1) Book Details
   * Introduction
   * Comments //this should goto Comments in Book details page.
2) Other page
   * ....
```

Book Detail Page

```
* Introduction
    ...
* Comments
    ...
```

I can see the **link** option under **+** button. How to tell to visit "Comments" ?

Answer (score 1):

Following is the one way i figured out.

First create anchor target.

- Put cursor where we need anchor target.
- Click "+" ("Goto Insert mode contents")
- Click Other macros and choose anchor.
- Type "Achor name" and click "Save" .

To link to that anchor

- Choose Links under "+" then click "Advanced"
- Type "Page Title#Anchor Name"